# VBA Debug Print ParamArray Error 13 Type Mismatch Values

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access VBA, I am trying to print the values of a parsed Parameter array but keep getting a Runtime Error 13 - Type Mismatch. The values in the array are mixed types i.e. Double, String, Long.

Code as follows:

```
Function MyArray() as Variant

Dim MyParams(2) as Variant
MyParams(0) = "3459"
MyParams(1) = "3345"
MyParams(2) = "34.666"

MyArray = MyParams

End Function

Sub PrintArray(ParamArray Params() As Variant)

    Dim p_param as Variant

    For Each p_param in Params
        Debug.Print params < - Error occurs here
    Next p_param

End Sub
```

I tried converting to string etc but it still wont work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `p_param ` is empty

Comment: So I am obviously doing something wrong. All I need to do is print the values of my Params array to the immediate window using a for each loop. How could I do this with what I have?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

Comment: Looks like your working with Function, so why `sub` ? should be `Function PrintArray(ParamArray Params() As Variant)`

Comment: How are you invoking the procedure? If you're passing an array, then `Params()` will have 1 parameter and your loop will be iterating once, and `p_param` will be the array you meant to be iterating. ..and that would be a *type mismatch* error.

Comment: Also a `Sub` procedure is delimited with `End Sub`. `End Function` normally delimits a `Function` procedure.

Comment: I am using a separate function to build my 1D array and then passing it to the sub I posted earlier. I just posted the function for building the array.

Comment: No more ideas anyone?

Comment: You can't do that. Answer on the way.

Comment: The line must read `Debug.Print p_param`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to iterate the `ParamArray` values, you need to understand what arguments you're receiving.

Say you have this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ParamArray values() As Variant)
```

The cool thing about `ParamArray` is that it allows the calling code to do this:

```
DoSomething 1, 2, "test"
```

If you're in `DoSomething`, what you receive in `values()` is 3 items: the numbers `1` & `2`, and a string containing the word `test`.

However what's happening in your case, is that you're doing something like this:

```
DoSomething Array(1, 2, "test")
```

And when you're in `DoSomething`, what you receive in `values()` is 1 item: an array containing the numbers `1` & `2`, and a string containing the word `test`.

The bad news is that you can't control how the calling code will be invoking that function.

The good news is that you can be flexible about it:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ParamArray values() As Variant)
    If ArrayLenth(values) = 1 Then
        If IsArray(values(0)) Then
            PrintArray values(0)
        End If
    Else
        PrintArray values
    End If
End Sub
```

```
Public Function ArrayLength(ByRef target As Variant) As Long
    Debug.Assert IsArray(target)
    ArrayLength = UBound(target) - LBound(target) + 1
End Function
```

Now either way can work:

```
DoSomething 1, 2, "test"
DoSomething Array(1, 2, "test")
```

Comment: @ Mathieu - Hey thanks for the answer it doesn't make a lot of sense just now but it is because I am not too familiar with the use of ParamArrays, rather, just arrays that I have built myself and hence have not really encountered any issues with debug printing them when I needed to. I will look into it and post back if I need any further clarity. Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: @tamosa basically ParamArray is building the array from whatever parameters are passed by the caller: if you pass an array, then you're looking at an array that contains an array, so you need to pull it out of the first index of the paramarrray array before you csn iterate it. BTW you should be iterating arrays with a `For...Next` loop, not `For Each`.

Answer (score 0):

If an element of the passed in `Params()` array is an array itself then treat it as such, otherwise just print...

```
Private Sub PrintArray(ParamArray Params() As Variant)

    Dim p_param As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For Each p_param In Params
        If IsArray(p_param) Then
            For i = LBound(p_param) To UBound(p_param)
                Debug.Print p_param(i)
            Next
        Else
            Debug.Print p_param
        End If
    Next p_param

End Sub
```